# Does iTextSharp-5.5.10 have a built-in stamp annotation style?

Tags: pdf, itext

I used itextsharp-5.5.10 to make a stamp annotation with the appearance of a picture.The current appearance of the seal depends on the picture.Now I want a bubble border like a cloud or some other style, so I need to deal with it when drawing the image. Can itextsharp-5.5.10 have a built-in method to solve my problem?
Now I use this code:

```
... ...
//create image
... ...
//create rectangle
... ...
//create appearance
PdfAppearance pdfApp = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(pdfStamper.Writer, (float)img.Width, (float)img.Height);
pdfApp.AddImage(img, (float)img.Width, 0, 0, (float)img.Height, 0, 0);
//create annotation
PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(pdfStamper.Writer, rect);
annotation.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, pdfApp);
annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.STAMP);
annotation.Put(PdfName.T, new PdfString(strAuthor, PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
annotation.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(strAnnotation, PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
annotation.Put(PdfName.M, new PdfDate());
annotation.Put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_READONLY));
// Add annotation to PDF
pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, iPage);
... ...
```